# jquery add opacity while scrolling and loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pjax

So I have a page that is loaded through pjax (non-pjax in IE) where a you have a bunch of links at the bottom.

Everytime you click on the hyperlinks , I make it scroll to the top of the page.

What's happening is that it scrolls to the top of the page while the page is still loading.

I am fine with that, but I was wondering is there a way to add some opacity while the page is loading?
Note: I am not sure of a solution that would work in both pjax and non-pjax enabled browsers.

```
$(document).on('click', 'my-link a', function() {
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
})
```

;

Comment: Where do you want to opacity to be added? To body?

Comment: $("body").css({ opacity: 0.5 });

Comment: I need the opacity when the page is loading via pjax or a regular load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally find your question really hard to understand, but I made an example for  you:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GCBKU/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="loader"></div>    
    <div id="content">
        <img src="http://0.tqn.com/d/studenttravel/1/0/i/T/Silleteros-1.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $("body").css({ opacity: 1.0 });
})
```

CSS:

```
body {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

While page is loading, `body` is set to `opacity 0.5`, after page is finished loading, `opacity` will be set to `1.0`.

Also added code to example fiddle that will not load image from cache, so that effect will always shown when fiddle is run (if effect is not shown when running it first time, try running it again). Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what content is beeing loaded you can add event listeners for onload then scroll / change opacity to lower value on 'onclick' event and revert on 'onload'.